# Как расставить индексы на таблицу

Tags: sql, запрос, sql-server, индексы, index

Доброго времени суток. У меня есть таблица следующей структуры

```
myTable
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    SId int NOT NULL,
    IsEnabled bit NOT NULL,
    MessageId int NULL,
)
```

Где Id - primary key, UserId, Sid и MessageId - foreign keys на другие таблицы.

Также у меня есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE 
    (@SId IS NULL OR SId = @SId) 
AND (@UserId IS NULL OR UserId = @UserId) 
AND (@IsEnabled IS NULL OR IsEnabled = @IsEnabled)
```

Причем особенность этого запроса в том что параметр @SId может быть равен NULL (то есть WHERE будет происходить по полям UserId  и IsEnabled), иногда 
параметр @UserId будет равен NULL (то есть запрос будет по SId  и IsEnabled )
а иногда и все три параметра будут указаны (то есть запрос будет происходить по
трем полям). Также отмечу что это единственный запрос к таблице, других нет

Собственно сам вопрос: как правильно будет построить индексы для такого запроса - по каким полям, в какой последовательности и сколько их должно быть, этих индексов? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал один индекс на три поля, используемые в фильтре запроса. Это нормальная практика делать индекс охватывающий все поля, участвующие в фильтре. И такой индекс оптимизатор будет использовать в первую очередь. Если сделать три отдельных индекса то из них будет использоваться только один(причем не факт что оптимизатору даже будет легче использовать один их этих трех индексов, а не кластерный индекс). По поводу того делать ли индекс на поле типа bit то тут все зависит от данных - если, например из 1000 записей только 10 будут со значением 1, т.е. `true`, а остальные `false` и фильтр будет по значению 1, то оптимизатор обязательно будет использовать индекс, т.к. это существенно сократит время поиска. Поэтому поле типа bit при составном индексе лучше добавить в секцию `include`.

Comment: один индекс не работает, если нужен поиск по второму и третьему полю индекса, без первого, или только по третьему.  Сервер умеет складывать отдельные индексы через битмап карты. Поэтому индексов надо три нужны на все три поля, (учитывая селективность само собой,  по IsEnabled  возможно и не понадобится)

Comment: по поводу того, что индекс не сработает - не соглашусь, тем более если будут участвовать 2 поля! Насчет того что он умеет складывать индексы - это наверное в том случае если нет индекса покрывающего все поля, а как я понял из вопроса все три поля всегда будут в фильтре. По поводу того что при фильтре по одному полю оптимизатор использует некластерный индекс вместо кластерного - большой вопрос!

Comment: если в составном индексе из двух полей искать по ВТОРОМУ полю - поиск НЕ РАБОТАЕТ.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "поиск НЕ РАБОТАЕТ" ?

Comment: не будет index seek, будет index scan. я уж не знаю как понятнее объяснить-то

Comment: "не знаю как понятнее объяснить"-четко формулируйте свой ответ. Под "поиск не работает" можно понять так же что индекс не будет использоваться(и не только это)! Что касается индексов - автор вопроса сказал что будет только такой запрос(т.е. в фильтре будут все три поля) а значит индекс будет работать так как нужно.

Comment: ок.  Если @SId будет NULL - индекс по трем полям использоваться НЕ БУДЕТ !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Три индекса на каждое поле - самый сбалансированный вариант.

Объясню почему. Во-первых композитный индекс не применяется, если в запросе не используются все поля из этого индекса. Во-вторых, кроме чтения вам же еще таблицу обновлять нужно, добавлять записи. При этом ваши индексы будут так же обновляться, на это тоже требуются ресурсы. И если индексов много ресурсы ощутимые, особенно если много композитных индексов. Вот почитайте http://www.sql.ru/articles/mssql/03013101indexes.shtml

Судя по названиям, это у вас какой-то месенджер, поэтому ваша таблица будет очень интенсивно обновляться. Вообще это все исследовать нужно - на реальной нагрузке погонять в разных вариантах.

Comment: а можно немного аргументов? Мне ваш ответ кажется очень противоречивым. Во-первых насколько я понимаю три отдельных индекса будут мало полезны в случае если поиск будет идти по всем трем полям одновременно а во-вторых насколько я знаю индексы по битовым полям вообще то ли запрещены то ли не имеют смысла то есть делать индекс по полю IsEnabled скорее всего не надо

Comment: Не мало полезны, а немного менее полезны, но гораздо лучше чем вообще без индексов. Зато отдельные индексы подходят под все по сути 6 вариантов запросов.

Comment: Почему шесть? На битовые поля индексы не нужны насколько я знаю. Получается три индекса - на SID, на UserId и на SID и UserId

Comment: 6 вариантов запросов, а не индексов

Comment: поменяйте тип `IsEnabled` на числовой и все

Comment: Вариантов запроса три, а не шесть (они указаны в вопросе). Менять IsEnabled на числовой нет ни возможности ни смысла

Comment: Да не 3, а 2^3 то есть 8.  Я отбросил варианты с тремя NULL так как фактически это будет select без условий, и с тремя не NULL так как ... в голове уже записалось решение с тремя индексами. Ладно, в общем их 8 и один можно отбросить так как не подходит под нашу задачу. Их 7!

Comment: еще раз повторю - всего запросов три. Не больше не меньше. Все они перечислены в вопросе. Другие запросы меня не интересуют

Comment: ты не понял о чем речь даже. ну ладно

Comment: @Ivan это я не понял или JuniorThree?

Comment: JuniorThree не понял

Answer (score 0):

Вообще тут и вариантов нет.  На внешние ключи вообще best practice иметь индексы, по многим причинам (погуглите) в итоге на UserId и на Sid  у вас уже будут два индекса. Дальше  определите селективность isEnabled  и решите нужен ли третий. 
Все.